# Problema para subir los cambios del proyecto local al repositorio remoto

Tags: vscode, github

consulta, necesito unabmano para solucionar lo siguiente: Quiero subir cambios, que tienen archivos y carpetas al repo remoto y no se que hice que me aparecen dos MM o, U y A al mismo tiempo, y al hacer git add ., git commit -m "msj" y git push, no me actualiza el repo remoto. Y me siguen quedando duplicados esos estados de archivos con o sin seguimiento, como soluciono eso porfa[image: print de VSC]?

Comment: qué mensajes te dice la consola cuando ejecutas los comandos add, commit y push